# composer and amazon php sdk

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html) on downloading the amazon-php-sdk. In the last step it says To use it, just add the following line to your code’s bootstrap process.

```
require '/path/to/sdk/vendor/autoload.php';
```

What is my code's bootstrap process in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, once you have added dependencies to composer.json and update/install the vendors, you are ready to use them.

Because, Symfony2 bootstrap uses composer autoload already.

> To ensure optimal flexibility and code reuse, Symfony2 applications
>   leverage a variety of classes and 3rd party components. But loading
>   all of these classes from separate files on each request can result in
>   some overhead. To reduce this overhead, the Symfony2 Standard Edition
>   provides a script to generate a so-called bootstrap file, consisting
>   of multiple classes definitions in a single file. By including this
>   file (which contains a copy of many of the core classes), Symfony no
>   longer needs to include any of the source files containing those
>   classes. This will reduce disc IO quite a bit.

FYI: [use-bootstrap-files](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/performance.html#use-bootstrap-files)